# Different behaviour between browsers reading binary with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, readfile

I am trying to read a binary file MyFile.xxx that is at the same domain as MyFile.html. Using JQuery I just try to display an alert with the number of characters in MyFile.xxx, and print the numeric representation of each one. However, I get different results depending on the browser:

**Google Chrome:** I correctly get an alert displaying 33, and the correct integers
**Firefox:** Alert displays "Undefined" and no integers are printed.
**IE9:** Alert displays "1" and no integers are printed.

Any ideas? Thanks

**MyFile.html**

```
<html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $.get('/MyFile.xxx', function(a){
    var l=a.length,x=[l];
    alert(l);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
      x[i]=a[i].charCodeAt(0);
      document.write(x[i]);
      document.write("<br>");
    }    
});                              
 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

Comment: Please show the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax( "/MyFile.xxx", {
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    },

    success: function( data ) {
        var len = data.length,
            str = "";

        for( var i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
            var byte = data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
            str += byte + " ";

        }
        document.body.innerHTML = str;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SXgfu/ (Shows the UTF-8 bytes for `åöä`)

Note that IE9 does not support this. It does not support any other ways of getting raw bytes of the response either.

If you are using PHP, you could use this work-around for IE:

```
$.get("/base64encoder.php?file=MyFile.xxx", function(data) {
    data = decode64(data);
    var len = data.length,
        str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        var byte = data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
        str += byte + " ";
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = str;
}, "text");
```

Where `base64encoder.php` is something like:

```
<?php
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents( $_GET['file'] ));
```

*remember* to sanitize the above, otherwise it's a huge security vulnerability

and `decode64` (src http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html):

```
var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
           "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
           "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
           "wxyz0123456789+/" +
           "=";

function decode64(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
    var i = 0;
    // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
    var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
    if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" + "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" + "Expect errors in decoding.");
    }
    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
    do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
        if (enc3 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
    } while (i < input.length);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works correctly for Chrome and Firefox, but as you said it doesn't work for IE9. Do you mean that it is impossible to read a binary file from Internet Explorer? Thank you

Comment: @Arturo yes. You have to use work around like sending the binary as base64 and decoding it on the client or such.

Comment: When I say binary file I mean "no text" file, but I believe your comment still applies. Thank you. If you have a link about that base64 encoding it would be great.